# Hydraulic disc brake clicks once when I pull the brake lever and the braking force is very bad

Tags: mountain-bike, disc-brake, hydraulic-disc-brake, trek, clicking

I have a brand new Trek Marlin 5 (1-2 months old) with hydraulic disc brakes and the rear brake doesn’t work well and when I pull the brake lever, it clicks once somewhere in the frame (cables inner routed).

Comment: You should take this back to the shop you bought it from; that's way too soon for anything to be wearing out.

Answer (score 4):

First, don't ride the bike if one of the brakes is not working properly. Not working well can change to not working at all and put you in a dangerous situation.

Take the bike back to the store where you bought it, a 2 month old bike with a major brake problem should be fixed under warranty. In any case if you do not have experience diagnosing and repairing hydraulic brakes you should have a professional address this problem.

The problem is likely that the rear brake has lost hydraulic fluid, or perhaps a seal has broken in the lever or caliper.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on hydraulic brakes with inner routing can be just cable hitting a frame when moving under increased tension. What is exact problem with braking? - do you need to apply extra force to brake or you feel like rotor is still spinning even under max pressure?

Comment: Unlike with cables, I can't feel any of my brake hoses move under increased hydraulic pressure.  So for properly installed hoses, I don't think the hose could "just" be hitting the frame.